# Filter an array of urls which must contain specific text and not contain other text

Tags: php, regex, validation, url, filtering

I want to extract specific links from a website.

The links look like that:

```
/topic/Funny/G1pdeJm
```

The links are always the same - except the last random chars.

I'm getting hard time to combine these parts

```
(preg_match("/^http:\/\//i",$str) || is_file($str))
```

and

```
(preg_match("/Funny(.*)/", $str) || is_file($str))
```

first code extract every links
second extract from the links only the /topic/Funny/* part.

Unfortunately, I can't combine them, also I want to also block these tags:

```
/topic/Funny/viral
/topic/Funny/time
/topic/Funny/top
/topic/Funny/top/week
/topic/Funny/top/month
/topic/Funny/top/year
/topic/Funny/top/all
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try using negative lookaheads to "filter out" the urls you don't like:

```
.*\/Funny\/(?!viral|time|top\/week|top\/month|top\/year|top\/all|top(\n|$)).*
```

[demo here](https://regex101.com/r/jGr9gi/3)

Comment: I think it will be nice if you put it inside the `preg_match` so the OP will understand the usage of this regex :)

Comment: honestly i'm a regex guy, not a PHP guy, or I would do that :)

Comment: thx a ton! This regex seems perfect :) but unfortunately, as @Dekel said i can't get it to work in my script :/

Answer (score 0):

I'll prepare a battery of test strings and show the implementation of using a regex to filter the URLs.

Regex Breakdown:

```
^
http://                              #match literal characters
[^/]+                                #match one or more non-slash characters (domain portion)
/topic/Funny/                        #match literal characters
(?!                                  #not followed by:
   viral                             #viral
   |time                             #OR time
   |top(?:/week|/month|/year|/all)?  #OR top, top/week, top/month, top/year, top/all
)
```

Implementation: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/inOIY))

```
$tests = [
    'http://example.com/topic/Funny/G1pdeJm',
    'http://example.com/topic/Funny/viral',
    'http://example.com/topic/Funny/time',
    'http://example.com/topic/Funny/top',
    'http://example.com/topic/Funny/top/week',
    'http://example.com/topic/Funny/top/month',
    'http://example.com/topic/Funny/top/year',
    'http://example.com/topic/Funny/top/all',
    'http://example.com/topic/NotFunny/IL2dsRq',
];

$result = [];
foreach ($tests as $str) {
    if (preg_match('~^http://[^/]+/topic/Funny/(?!viral|time|top(?:/week|/month|/year|/all)?)~', $str)) {
        $result[] = $str;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'http://example.com/topic/Funny/G1pdeJm',
)
```